# How does linux kernel wake idle processor up when new task created?

Tags: kernel, arm, scheduler, irq

I'm newbie on Linux Kernel.
Currently, I looked into idle codes and had a quesition.
When processor doesn't have any taks in their own runqueue then it may
go into idle mode, specific WFI(wating for interrupt). 
(All I mentioned is about ARM architecture not X86. So something is wrong for X86.)
After staying in WFI state, maybe other processor(not idle) want to spread
their task to this, idle processor(by load balance). At that time a busy processor
makes task imigrated. In my point of view, when the task is imigrated, the idle processor
should wake up immidiatley to process the task. right? However, I couldn't find
any codes waking up idle processor but only found codes about registering task to idle processor's runqueue.

I'd like to know what mechanism is behind of waking processor up when new task is given.
Or it just move task from one queue to other's than let it be until woken up by
some unpredictable IRQ?

Please show me the truth :)

Answer (score 6):

`WFI` is a special co-processor instruction for the ARM.  For example,

```
 ENTRY(cpu_arm946_do_idle)
         mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c0, 4           @ Wait for interrupt
         mov     pc, lr
```

It has nothing to do with Linux (directly).

There is a special `idle` task that runs the `WFI` instruction on the ARM, if there is no work to do.  The `idle` task is the very lowest priority Linux task, scheduled if there is nothing else.  If `WFI` is done by `idle`, some driver will interrupt (maybe a timer) when there is no work to do.  In the SMP case, it will not go to `idle` if there are other processes that can be migrated; the scheduler checks this.  If a load gets high, then the busy processor needs to `wake` the others;  In the case of an **ARM** with an interrupt.  Usually this handling is in **arch/*arch*/kernel/process.c**.  For example the *x86* has [`default_idle()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/kernel/process.c;hb=HEAD).  I don't know specifics of how the *x86* works, but you can look at the source.

For your question **How does linux kernel wake idle processor up when new task created?**, the answer is it doesn't.  Only `fork()` (and some similar functions) can create a new task; originally from the `init` task and then one of it's children.  If you have a `cron` job, it will have scheduled a timer before it goes to `sleep/idle`.  This timer will wake the system, re-schedule `cron` and then `cron` will call `fork()`, to create the new task.

Other related mechanisms are [`cpufreq`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree;f=drivers/cpufreq;hb=HEAD), [`cpuidle`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree;f=drivers/cpuidle;hb=HEAD), [`kernel/power`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree;f=kernel/power;hb=HEAD) etc.

The **truth** is always *objective/subjective* and certainly is not **global**.  Show me the `metric` for the **truth** and I can show you the **truth**.

Answer (score 2):

`smp_send_reschedule()` will send `IPI_RESCHEDULE` to the processor that is idle. This will wake it up from `wfi`. It is called from couple of places, one example being `wake_up_process -> try_to_wake_up -> try_to_wake_up -> ttwu_queue -> ttwu_queue_remote` (function names from kernel 3.4).

Answer (score 0):

just set the CPU's flag like below code after create the thread.

```
 = > thread's task_struct->flags |= PF_WAKE_UP_IDLE;
```

Comment: This is for thread wakeup, not for CPU wakeup. PF_WAKE_UP_IDLE flag is absent in Linux kernel 3.18 and later.

Answer (score 0):

look at select_task_rq_fair(), which is CFS::select_task_rq() method.
This is most representative case where the scheduler wakes up the idle task for re-balancing run-queues.