# Which function is called for waking up a cpu on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have been studying thread context switch functionality of Linux kernel on x86. I can see that there is a kernel function "cpu_idle" to move a cpu into  an idle state. However, I am unable to find the kernel function that is called to wake-up an idle CPU. Please let me know where I can find the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a function to wake the CPU. In the idle state, the CPU is waiting for a system-level interrupt. Usually from a driver after a hardware event or from a previously scheduled timer like a cron job.

This answer has more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15096339/50177